# Quiver pivot table from linked Object sets

Tags: palantir-foundry

Three Object types are linked in Quiver creating a transform table. I would like to use the data of the linked Object Types in the transform table in a (Quiver) pivot table. The advice of Foundry AIP :
Yes, you can use a transform table with data from linked Object types in a Quiver pivot table. First, create a transform table with an object set as its input and use the Join to Linked Objects transformation to join linked objects into the table. Second Then, create a pivot table in Quiver and choose the transform table with the joined data as the Input Object Set.
Here is the challenge: the Input Object set button only shows Object Sets and not the required Transform table.
How can I add the data from the linked Object sets in the transform tablet the pivot table. All support is welcome.